# Go Up A Level cards

Tags: munchkin

If I draw a "Go Up A Level" card, is it automatically played/applied right away or do I have the option to hold it in my hand?

I ask for a more specific reason, because I drew a "Go Up A Level" card with the restriction that I could not be the player of the highest level or tied with the highest level.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can keep 'Go Up A Level' cards in your hand until you choose to play them, you do not have to play them right away.

From the [Munchkin Rules](http://www.worldofmunchkin.com/rules/munchkin_rules.pdf):

> Go Up a Level cards may be played on yourself or any other player at any time, even during combat. Discard them once they are played.

Obviously if you can play them during combat you do not have to use them immediately.